# How to add a class to a select dropdown loop using ERB

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have the following loop to create a select dropdown using ERB. It is working correctly.

```
  <%= f.select(:player_id) do %>
    <% @players.each do |p| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", value: p.id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

My question is how do I add a class to the select element?

I have tried the following:

```
<%= f.select(:player_id), class: "form-control" do %>
    <% @players.each do |p| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", value: p.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= f.select(:player_id), { class: "form-control" } do %>
    <% @players.each do |p| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", value: p.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have seen questions similar to this, but none that use a loop like the example above.

Comment: Try JavaScript to add class to the select element, like `$(your_select_element).addClass('.your-class-name')`

Comment: I thought about that, but I would prefer to do it inline if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<%= f.select :player_id, options_for_select( @players.collect { |player| ["#{player.first_name} #{player.last_name}", player.id] } ), {}, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
<%= f.select :player_id, options_for_select( @players.collect { |player| ["#{player.first_name} #{player.last_name}", player.id] } ), class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: Does not quite work, but got me to what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with your code is `f.select(:player_id)`.

You are calling the select method with only one parameter `:player_id`. So you can pass other options like this.

```
<%= f.select :player_id, class: "form-control" do %>
  <% @players.each do |p| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}", value: p.id) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```